# Changing GET to POST in Middleware - SLIM Framework 3

Tags: routes, slim, middleware, slim-3

I'm working on a Rest API with SLIM FRAMEWORK 3, and I need to check if a GET call returns a specific data in Middleware. If no data is returned, I need to make a new call with the POST method first to write the data in the API, and then to continue with $next().

I tried the withRedirect(), but it seems to only work with GET. Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

```
<?php

$app->add(function($req, $res, $next){
$uri = $req->getUri()->getPath();

//get query_string params
$params = $req->getUri()->getQuery();
parse_str($params, $args);

//check if is desired route...
if($req->isGet() && isset($args['name']) && isset($args['borndate']) && $uri == 'api/v1/example'){
    global $app;

    //try to get data from DB 
    $dados_mapa = (new App\Models\MyExampleModel())->get()
            ->where('name', '=', $args['name'])
            ->where('borndate', '=', $args['borndate'])
            ->first();

    //check data
    if(isset($dados_mapa->id))
    {
        //data exists, continue
        return $next($req, $res);

    }else{

        //no data, I need to do a POST call here...
        $new_post_uri = 'api/v1/example';

        doPostHere($new_post_uri); ////how to make this POST?

        //continue with the first call
        return $next($req, $res);

    }

  }

});
```

Comment: If you want the middleware to apply only to certain routes, then you do not need to add it to $app. Add middleware to route itself.

Comment: This sounds like something the client should do, and not your server; also middleware making POST requests - sounds iffy.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara Thanks. You're right!

Comment: @zedling Thanks. Maybe I have to change it, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, use [`Guzzle`](http://guzzlephp.org) to do a POST request as you want to do a new HTTP call and Guzzle is quite a good HTTP client for PHP.

However, be aware that this is a particularly poor pattern to use and you should not do this. A GET should not have side-effects and creating new data is certainly a side-effect!

A better pattern would be to return a 4xx error if the data doesn't exist and then get the client to do the POST request to create it.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.

Comment: Thank you. These are very useful tips. I'll rethink the logic (but it's interesting to know that Guzzle is an option in these cases)